# What contract is in consumer-driven contract testing?

Tags: testing, methodology

[Consumer-Driven Contracts: A Service Evolution Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) presents the idea of contracts verification.

But how detailed is the contract?

- Is the contract defining only a syntax of requests/responses? Like WSDL in the case of SOAP Web services.
- Or does it describes also the order of messages, i.e., the protocol? e.g.:

[image: FIPA-Subscribe-Protocol]

- Or does it define also the behaviour of a system? In other words if I send request R and system is in state S I should receive response W? For instance, if I send a request to buy two monitors and the shop has only one monitor I should get negative but when I request only one monitor I should receive a receipt?

Comment: Identical answered question here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/what-contract-is-in-consumer-driven-contract-testing  Was that answer not what you were looking for?

Comment: Don't post the same question on multiple sites.

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid full behaviour simulation.

---

**What's a contract?**

A contract is a *set of shared expectations* between a service that acts as a consumer and another service that acts like a producer. They focus the specification and delivery of service functionality around key business value drivers. The compatibility of a contract should remain stable and immutable for a particular set of consumer contracts and expectations.

**Expectations**

As a consumer, we need to exactly define our expectations. For example, when sending a request from the consumer to the producer, we want to make sure that we receive a successful response that matches our request.

**Purpose**

*The purpose of contract testing is not to start writing business features in the contracts*. Stay focused and limit yourself to testing contracts between applications and avoid full behaviour simulation.

---

You can read more about contracts here: http://ordepdev.me/posts/boost-your-confidence-with-consumer-driven-contracts.